# InventTrans and InventJournalTrans tables

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Starting with:

**InventJournalName**

> The InventJournalName table contains information for inventory journal
>   names. The table is used to initialize inventory journals and assign
>   the default values from the InventJournalName table to the inventory
>   journal and functions as a template for the inventory journals.

As far as I understand here I have a list of journals, with their types.

Using the JournalNameId and JournalType we can add a new record in the:

**InventJournalTable**

> The InventJournalTable table contains information about inventory
>   journals. The table holds information about how the journal should be
>   handled by the system, e.g., how is should be posted.

InventJournalTable will make use of the fields in InventJournalName in order to "instantiate" its fields. Is this correct? So we will have many journals with their respective journal types.

And now comes the:

**InventJournalTrans**

> The InventJournalTrans table contains information about items and
>   represents a line in an inventory journal. Each record has information
>   related to a specific item and is related to a record in the
>   InventJournalTable which is the journal header.

So, every line in the InventJournalTrans  will be linked to a journal from InventJournalTable.

I think I get this but then, what's the role of InventTrans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tables are all for inventory journals, which are more like manual inventory changes.  An example being if a user wanted to transfer 100 widgets from warehouse **A** to warehouse **B** they could create a transfer journal.

Look at `Inventory and warehouse management>Journals`.  A similar set of tables would be

- `LedgerJournalName`
- `LedgerJournalTable`
- `LedgerJournalTrans`

Which are under `General Ledger>Journals`

**InventTrans** (importantly paired with `InventTransOrigin`) is for tracking all inventory transactions that happen from anywhere pretty much.  If you produce a **widget** in production and it has parts **w1, w2, w3** on its BOM that make it up, you'll see those transactions in `InventTrans`. If you create a sales order and sell that **widget** to a customer, you'll see that transaction in there.

**And lastly**, back to the original journal example, if you transfer from warehouse **A** to warehouse **B**, it will show up as two transactions there as well.

Comment: So ... what you are saying is .. InventTrans contains all the InventJournalTrans records and some others more? Transactions in w1, w2, w3 example will show up in InventTrans but not in InventJournalTrans?

Comment: Table `InventTrans` contains inventory transactions from other origins than journals: sales orders, purchase orders, production orders etc.